# How to keep the REST authentication credentials in AngularJS on page reload?

Tags: http, rest, angularjs, basic-authentication

We built a RESTful server, quite 'pure', which uses HTTP BASIC AUTHENTICATION. This means the client needs to send username/password every request. It is simple and secure (over HTTPS). REST of course is stateless and uses no sessions, so there is no 'logon' method in the API. Every request needs to be authorized again.

On this REST server we built an AngularJS client. This is a single page application. When the user logs in to the client, the client will store the credentials and make sure the correct HTTP headers are set.

The “problem” is that when the user refreshes the browser, the app looses its state, including the authentication credentials.

What is the best way to deal with this? How can the AngularJS app keep the user logged in / remember the credentials? Whatever the solution, it MUST be secure, since it is a banking application.

Comment: I would guess you need to use some of the new local storage APIs in the browser though I'm unaware of AngularJS hooks into those APIs (you may just need to access them directly) http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html http://caniuse.com/#search=local

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't this limit browser compatibility?

Comment: @shaunhusain Yes, AngularJS do have such functionality: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: PatrickSavalle did you see the second of the two links I put there? It has caniuse.com link to check for local storage compatibility.  If you need to support IE 6 sorry, if you need to support IE 7 (7 yrs old) I understand but it's a shame.  @Sindre thanks for the tip.  Also agree on the storage of hashed password or token rather than any plaintext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, this is a tricky one. One possible solution is to use some combination of e.g. Javascrypt (http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/) and temporary localstorage/cookie.

Do not store the password at all, not even in localstorage. You can use a key derivation function to get a key from the password. With a salt and a reasonable number of iterations this could be secure enough.

Update:

See this [securely store user password locally in a jquery mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865943/securely-store-user-password-locally-in-a-jquery-mobile-app) for another good answer

Comment: Is there a graceful degradation for browsers that are not supported by the AngularJS local storage?

Comment: The LocalStorageModul found here, github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage, has fallback to cookie-storage. Other then that, see @shaunhusain answer

Comment: Does this mean that the password is encrypted and decrypted client side?

Comment: No, you should never store a password. Instead, derive some secret key from the password, salt it, and then you could use this instead. That will prevent interceptors from learning valuable information. Furthermore a token storing technique is advisable, e.g. oauth2, and then the token can be stored and then this token could be encrypted/decrypted

Comment: We solved it by returning a temp. secret token upon login. The client passes this token in the password filed of the HTTP BASIC AUTH. This is stored in the local storage on the browser side and in the db on the server side. We do some additional checks such as a fingerprint and expiration etc. Thanks for helping. One last question, should we bcrypt this temp. token like we bcrypt our passwords?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, I agree with Sindre but, here's the full list of browsers from [StatCounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201206-201306-bar)

IE 7 Market Share is .86%, if you're going to support that you have to support the 2% Linux users :).  Just wanted to put this out there so as to have some sort of gauge on what's being used... these numbers are obviously not 100% accurate but it seems reasonable.

I think without using local/web storage APIs you can't really achieve this.

```
Browser Version Market Share Perc. (June 2012 to June 2013)
IE 9.0  15.49
IE 8.0  11.36
Chrome 23.0 5.63
Chrome 26.0 5.15
Chrome 21.0 4.55
Chrome 24.0 3.9
Chrome 22.0 3.59
Chrome 27.0 3.24
Safari iPad 3.19
Chrome 25.0 3.18
Chrome 20.0 2.59
Chrome 19.0 2.46
Firefox 16.0    2.42
IE 10.0 2.4
Firefox 14.0    2.19
Safari 5.1  2.11
Firefox 15.0    2.07
Firefox 19.0    1.97
Firefox 18.0    1.85
Firefox 13.0    1.84
Firefox 20.0    1.73
Safari 6.0  1.69
Firefox 17.0    1.67
Firefox 21.0    1.48
Firefox 12.0    1.43
IE 7.0  0.86
Firefox 3.6 0.73
Safari 5.0  0.68
Android 0   0.59
Opera 12.0  0.53
Opera 12.1  0.45
Firefox 10.0    0.42
Firefox 11.0    0.38
IE 6.0  0.38
Chrome 17.0 0.26
Firefox 9.0 0.26
Chrome 18.0 0.24
Firefox 4.0 0.22
Chrome 16.0 0.22
Firefox 8.0 0.21
Opera 11.6  0.18
360 Safe Browser 0  0.18
Chrome 15.0 0.17
Chrome 11.0 0.17
Chrome 14.0 0.16
Chrome 12.0 0.16
Chrome 13.0 0.15
Firefox 5.0 0.15
Firefox 3.0 0.15
Firefox 6.0 0.15
Firefox 7.0 0.14
Firefox 3.5 0.14
Chrome for Andr 0.14
Chrome iPad 0.13
Sony PS3 0  0.13
Chrome 10.0 0.12
Sogou Explorer 0    0.12
Safari 4.0  0.1
Firefox 22.0    0.09
Safari 4.1  0.09
Chrome 28.0 0.08
Yandex Browser 1.5  0.08
Silk 1.0    0.08
Maxthon 3.0 0.07
Chrome 8.0  0.07
Chrome 9.0  0.05
RockMelt 0.16   0.05
Chrome 7.0  0.05
Firefox 2.0 0.04
Chrome 6.0  0.04
Chrome 5.0  0.04
BlackBerry 0    0.04
Opera 11.5  0.04
Chrome 4.0  0.04
Chromium 18.0   0.03
Opera 0 0.03
Maxthon 4.0 0.03
Opera 10.6  0.02
Maxthon 3.4 0.02
Firefox 1.0 0.02
Opera 9.6   0.02
TheWorld    0.02
Opera 11.0  0.02
Yandex Browser 1.1  0.02
Opera 11.1  0.02
Chrome 3.0  0.02
Maxthon 1.0 0.02
Chromium 25.0   0.01
AppleWebKit 0   0.01
Opera 10.0  0.01
Tencent Traveler 4.0    0.01
Silk 2.9    0.01
Opera 10.1  0.01
Netscape 4.7    0.01
Chrome 2.0  0.01
Maxthon 2.0 0.01
Chromium 20.0   0.01
Silk 3.0    0.01
Chrome 29.0 0.01
webOS Browser 0 0.01
QQ Browser 6.14 0.01
Mozilla 1.9 0.01
Chrome 18.6 0.01
Safari 3.0  0.01
Phantom 0   0.01
Firefox 23.0    0.01
Silk 2.7    0.01
Chrome 1.0  0.01
Firefox 1.5 0.01
Opera 10.5  0.01
Chrome 0.2  0.01
Camino 2.1  0.01
Silk 2.8    0.01
Safari 3.1  0.01
Opera 9.2   0.01
Opera 9.5   0.01
Maxthon 3.3 0.01
NetFront 4.2    0.01
Yandex Browser 1.7  0.01
Silk 2.4    0.01
IE 0    0
Safari 3.2  0
Kindle 0    0
Pale Moon 15.3  0
Opera 12.5  0
Flock 2.6   0
QQ Browser 6.12 0
360 0   0
Pale Moon 19.0  0
Chromium 22.0   0
Chrome 26.2 0
Unknown 0   0
QQ Browser 7.3  0
Chrome 24.2 0
Opera 9.0   0
Pale Moon 15.2  0
Pale Moon 15.4  0
SeaMonkey 2.17  0
Firefox 24.0    0
Chromium 24.0   0
Pale Moon 12.2  0
Pale Moon 20.0  0
Iron 19.0   0
Iron 18.0   0
Pale Moon 12.3  0
SeaMonkey 2.10  0
Chrome 23.4 0
Kindle 3.0  0
Lunascape 6.8   0
Chromium 17.0   0
NetFront 4.1    0
SeaMonkey 2.14  0
Iron 17.0   0
SeaMonkey 2.13  0
SeaMonkey 2.12  0
Chrome 27.1 0
SeaMonkey 2.11  0
Chromium 14.0   0
Pale Moon 20.1  0
QQ Browser 6.13 0
Windows Media Player 0  0
QQ Browser 7.1  0
SeaMonkey 2.0   0
SeaMonkey 2.15  0
Chromium 23.0   0
Pale Moon 3.6   0
Chrome 22.1 0
Pale Moon 11.0  0
SeaMonkey 2.16  0
Iron 16.0   0
Chrome 25.2 0
Pale Moon 15.1  0
Comodo Dragon 20.1  0
Mozilla 1.8 0
AOL 7.0 0
Pale Moon 15.0  0
Comodo Dragon 19.2  0
SeaMonkey 2.9   0
Chrome 23.1 0
Chromium 12.0   0
Flock 2.5   0
Safari 1.3  0
Lunascape 6.7   0
Safari 5.2  0
Iron 25.0   0
Pale Moon 12.0  0
Firefox 1.4 0
Opera 8.5   0
Netscape 7.2    0
Opera 8.0   0
Pale Moon 12.1  0
Safari 2.0  0
Chrome 0.3  0
Comodo Dragon 21.1  0
UC Browser 2.0  0
Flock 3.5   0
Chromium 13.0   0
Comodo Dragon 20.0  0
Yandex Browser 1.0  0
Comodo Dragon 21.0  0
Opera 7.0   0
QQ Browser 2.8  0
Comodo Dragon 15.0  0
Netscape 7.0    0
Iron 26.0   0
Opera 10.7  0
Samsung 0   0
Nokia 0 0
IE 5.5  0
QQ Browser 3.2  0
Netscape 8.1    0
Chrome 24.1 0
Firefox 3.1 0
QQ Browser 7.0  0
Comodo Dragon 19.1  0
Iron 15.0   0
Chromium 15.0   0
Epiphany 2.30   0
Fake IE 0   0
Silk 2.6    0
SeaMonkey 1.1   0
Midori 0.4  0
Chrome 0.4  0
K-Meleon 1.0    0
Iceweasel 2.0   0
Chromium 11.0   0
QQ Browser 3.0  0
Iron 14.0   0
Tencent Traveler 0  0
Iron 12.0   0
Iron 13.0   0
Chromium 10.0   0
Konqueror 3.5   0
Anonymouse 0    0
Maxthon 4.1 0
Chrome 25.1 0
UC Browser 0    0
QQ Browser 2.5  0
Comodo Dragon 16.1  0
UC Browser 2.3  0
Mozilla 1.7 0
Flock 2.0   0
Silk 2.2    0
SeaMonkey 2.7   0
OmniWeb 5.11    0
Iron 8.0    0
Camino 2.0  0
QQ Browser 0    0
Iron 10.0   0
QQ Browser 3.7  0
UC Browser 9.0  0
Midori 0.2  0
AOL 6.0 0
iBrowser 3.0    0
Beamrise 2.25   0
Opera 14.0  0
Silk 3.1    0
K-Meleon 1.5    0
Chrome 23.2 0
QQ Browser 3.1  0
WebTV/MSNTV 2.6 0
Chromium 16.0   0
Pale Moon 9.2   0
UC Browser 8.6  0
Iron 27.0   0
UC Browser 2.2  0
Pale Moon 8.0   0
Iron 7.0    0
Chrome 26.1 0
Iron 9.0    0
Iron 6.0    0
QQ Browser 7.2  0
IE 5.01 0
SeaMonkey 2.8   0
Iron 11.0   0
Opera 9.1   0
UC Browser 8.4  0
Safari 7.0  0
Chromium 8.0    0
QQ Browser 2.7  0
UC Browser 2.8  0
UC Browser 7.9  0
QQ Browser 3.5  0
Flock 1.2   0
Comodo Dragon 16.2  0
SeaMonkey 2.6   0
Epiphany 2.22   0
Pale Moon 9.1   0
Minefield 3.0   0
NetFront 3.5    0
Firefox 25.0    0
QQ Browser 4.1  0
Chromium 9.0    0
QQ Browser 2.6  0
Opera 7.1   0
Silk 1.1    0
MS OPD 0    0
Chromium 21.0   0
Pale Moon 7.0   0
SeaMonkey 2.4   0
Lunascape 6.5   0
Obigo 0 0
SeaMonkey 2.5   0
QQ Browser 4.0  0
Safari 1.0  0
Iron 5.0    0
Chrome 23.3 0
Camino 1.6  0
SeaMonkey 2.2   0
UC Browser 8.5  0
QQ Browser 4.2  0
Comodo Dragon 11.4  0
Comodo Dragon 10.0  0
QQ Browser 3.4  0
Safari 1.2  0
rekonq 0    0
Beamrise 2.23   0
Pale Moon 9.0   0
Netscape 4.03   0
Comodo Dragon 12.1  0
Iron 4.0    0
Dolfin 3.0  0
Pale Moon 4.0   0
IE 5.0  0
Comodo Dragon 8.0   0
UC Browser 7.8  0
Comodo Dragon 16.0  0
Chromium 7.0    0
Firefox 0   0
SeaMonkey 2.3   0
FrontPage 0 0
Chromium 28.0   0
Comodo Dragon 19.0  0
Minefield 4.0   0
QQ Browser 1.5  0
Comodo Dragon 14.0  0
rekonq 1.1  0
QQ Browser 4.3  0
Safari 0    0
Chrome 0.0  0
RockMelt 0.9    0
Comodo Dragon 18.1  0
NetFront 0  0
UC Browser 8.3  0
Opera 7.5   0
Chromium 6.0    0
Pale Moon 6.0   0
Lunascape 6.6   0
Pale Moon 5.0   0
Safari 6.1  0
QQ Browser 2.4  0
UC Browser 2.7  0
Beamrise 17.2   0
Jasmine 0.8 0
UC Browser 8.0  0
Chrome 30.0 0
Comodo Dragon 18.3  0
IE 4.01 0
SeaMonkey 2.18  0
RockMelt 0.8    0
Comodo Dragon 12.2  0
Comodo Dragon 13.4  0
Minefield 3.7   0
QQ Browser 6.11 0
Comodo Dragon 9.0   0
Chrome 27.2 0
Chromium 0  0
SeaMonkey 2.1   0
NetFront 3.4    0
UC Browser 8.2  0
Links 2.2   0
QQ Browser 6.9  0
QQ Browser 6.10 0
Netscape 4.79   0
Comodo Dragon 18.0  0
QQ Browser 2.3  0
NetSurf 0   0
Comodo Dragon 14.2  0
Netscape 7.1    0
UC Browser 1.0  0
QQ Browser 3.6  0
Safari 1.1  0
Comodo Dragon 17.4  0
Mozilla 1.0 0
Netscape 4.8    0
Iron 3.0    0
Comodo Dragon 17.5  0
Comodo Dragon 14.1  0
QQ Browser 2.2  0
QQ Browser 3.3  0
Opera 10.2  0
WebPositive 0   0
Opera 11.00 0
Chromium 27.0   0
Comodo Dragon 17.3  0
Comodo Dragon 13.0  0
rekonq 2.2  0
Camino 1.0  0
Dolphin 0   0
OmniWeb 5.0 0
UC Browser 2.6  0
Comodo Dragon 4.1   0
Microsoft URL Control 0 0
Konqueror 3.2   0
Comodo Dragon 17.1  0
Netscape 8.0    0
JoeDog 0    0
Skyfire 0   0
Galeon 2.0  0
Midori 0.3  0
SeaMonkey 1.0   0
Comodo Dragon 6.0   0
IE 5.1  0
Windows Media Player 11.0   0
SonyEricsson 0  0
Thunderbird 3.0 0
Netscape 6.2    0
UC Browser 8.8  0
Lunascape 0 0
Lynx 2.8    0
Epiphany 3.2    0
Lunascape 6.3   0
Links 2.1   0
Firebird 0  0
QQ Browser 2.1  0
Chrome 99.0 0
Amiga 0 0
QQ Browser 1.9  0
Chrome 17.1 0
Microsoft-WebDAV 0  0
UC Browser 7.7  0
Netscape 3.0    0
Comodo Dragon 13.2  0
Mozilla 1.6 0
Konqueror 3.1   0
Lunascape 6.4   0
QQ Browser 5.1  0
Lunascape 4.0   0
Netscape 4.5    0
Chrome 19.7 0
Konqueror 3.0   0
Webaroo 1.2 0
Sleipnir 2.0    0
Chrome 2.4  0
Camino 1.5  0
w3m 0.5 0
Konqueror 4.2   0
Jasmine 1.0 0
Flock 1.0   0
UC Browser 8.7  0
Squid 0 0
Galeon 1.0  0
Epiphany 3.0    0
Webaroo 1.3 0
Camino 2.2  0
Chromium 26.0   0
Iceweasel 10.0  0
Midori 0.1  0
Midori 0.01 0
Iron 2.0    0
Openwave Mobile Browser 0   0
Flock 1.1   0
QQ Browser 6.8  0
Konqueror 3.3   0
Dillo 2.0   0
Anonymous 0 0
Lunascape 6.1   0
IE 5.2  0
QQ Browser 2.0  0
iBrowser 3.1    0
Comodo Dragon 12.0  0
Epiphany 2.14   0
Silk 2.3    0
Chromium 5.0    0
Chrome 0.5  0
Lunascape 5.1   0
UC Browser 7.6  0
Opera 15.0  0
Chimera 0   0
QQ Browser 6.2  0
Flock 3.0   0
Chrome 3.1  0
Comodo Dragon 17.0  0
QQ Browser 5.0  0
Epiphany 1.2    0
SeaMonkey 2.19  0
Lunascape 2.1   0
QQ Browser 6.7  0
Puffin 3.91 0
rekonq 2.1  0
Midori 0    0
Silk 2.0    0
Epiphany 1.4    0
Mozilla 1.2 0
Mozilla 1.5 0
Mozilla 1.4 0
OmniWeb 5.10    0
Windows Media Player 9.0    0
rekonq 2.3  0
Comodo Dragon 4.0   0
Opera 7.2   0
SeaMonkey 1.5   0
Avant Browser 0 0
Konqueror 3.4   0
rekonq 2.0  0
IEMobile 9.0    0
Netscape 4.0    0
iTunes 0    0
ELinks 0.9  0
QQ Browser 1.4  0
WebTV/MSNTV 1.0 0
QQ Browser 6.0  0
QQ Browser 1.3  0
rekonq 1.3  0
UC Browser 8.9  0
Konqueror 4.1   0
RockMelt 3.0    0
QQ Browser 1.0  0
Iron 1.0    0
Lunascape 5.0   0
Camino 0.8  0
Puffin 3.93 0
Lunascape 6.0   0
Proxomitron 0   0
Lunascape 4.8   0
Lunascape 2.0   0
Dolfin 2.0  0
Iceweasel 3.5   0
Epiphany 2.20   0
Mozilla 1.3 0
Minefield 3.6   0
AOL 5.5 0
Pale Moon 3.5   0
iPhone 0    0
Chrome 2.1  0
Chrome 8.1  0
UC Browser 2.5  0
Baidu Explorer 1.4  0
ibisBrowser 0   0
Yandex Browser 2.0  0
Iron 0.2    0
Netscape 4.61   0
Silk 2.1    0
Midori 0.5  0
Flock 0.9   0
Lynx 0  0
QQ Browser 2.9  0
SeaMonkey 2.20  0
Flock 0.7   0
Camino 0.7  0
CoRom+ 27.0 0
Minefield 3.1   0
UC Browser 2.4  0
Tencent Traveler 5.0    0
ELinks 0.11 0
Opera 7.6   0
QQ Browser 6.5  0
Chrome 59.0 0
Lunascape 6.2   0
Lunascape 4.7   0
Iceweasel 17.0  0
Chrome 99.9 0
UC Browser 9.1  0
Chrome 42.0 0
Windows-Media-Player 10.0   0
Apple-PubSub 0  0
QQ Browser 1.2  0
Chrome 1.3  0
SaferSurf 0 0
Baidu Explorer 1.3  0
Minefield 3.2   0
iCab 3.0    0
Iceweasel 21.0  0
QQ Browser 6.6  0
Comodo Dragon 1.0   0
Netscape 6.1    0
Dillo 0.8   0
UC Browser 7.4  0
Opera 10.3  0
RockMelt 2.1    0
Sleipnir 4.1    0
Netscape 4.51   0
UC Browser 7.2  0
Chrome 26.9 0
UC Browser 7.0  0
SEMC Browser 0  0
Sleipnir 2.9    0
Beamrise 2.19   0
Epiphany 0.9    0
Baidu Explorer 2.0  0
Opera 5.0   0
iCab 2.9    0
iBrowser 2.8    0
Epiphany 0.8    0
Lunascape 1.4   0
Webaroo 2.0 0
Opera 8.1   0
BrowseX 0   0
UC Browser 7.5  0
IEMobile 7.0    0
Camino 3.0  0
Shiira 1.2  0
Netscape 4.6    0
Iron 0.3    0
NetPositive 2.2 0
Chrome 1.1  0
Opera 6.0   0
RockMelt 2.2    0
Iron 0  0
rekonq 1.0  0
Lunascape 1.1   0
Lunascape 3.6   0
Maxthon 0.0 0
rekonq 1.2  0
Yandex Browser 6.2  0
Baidu Explorer 1.2  0
QQ Browser 6.3  0
Mozilla 0   0
Pale Moon 0 0
Epiphany 1.6    0
SmallProxy 0    0
QQ Browser 1.1  0
UC Browser 8.1  0
Epiphany 2.18   0
Baidu Explorer 1.1  0
Netscape 6.0    0
IE 4.0  0
Chromium 19.0   0
Lunascape 3.0   0
Netbox 0    0
Opera 12.8  0
Lunascape 4.9   0
Microsoft Office Existence Discovery 0  0
Camino 4.0  0
Comodo Dragon 17.2  0
Windows Media Player 10.0   0
Sundance 1.2    0
rekonq 1.80 0
Emacs/W3 0  0
Firefox 99.0    0
fantomas fantomBrowser 0    0
Iceweasel 20.0  0
Lunascape 4.6   0
NetFront 3.3    0
Yandex Browser 2.1  0
Lunascape 1.0   0
QQ Browser 5.2  0
Lunascape 1.3   0
Lunascape 1.2   0
Maxthon 3.5 0
Iceweasel 18.0  0
Epiphany 2.16   0
Polaris 0   0
Chrome 32.0 0
Beamrise 4.20   0
RockMelt 1.0    0
Lunascape 3.5   0
Twitturly 0 0
SeaMonkey 9.23  0
Sleipnir 2.8    0
ELinks 0.10 0
Iceweasel 3.0   0
Epiphany 2.28   0
IE 4.5  0
Sundance 1.3    0
Flock 0.4   0
Epiphany 1.0    0
Chrome 24.3 0
ELinks 0.12 0
Epiphany 1.8    0
Lunascape 1.05  0
Camino 1.1  0
Dolfin 1.5  0
Sundance 0.9    0
Puffin 2.93 0
Baidu Explorer 1.0  0
SeaMonkey 0 0
Baidu Explorer 2.1  0
Flock 0.5   0
iBrowser 2.7    0
Mozilla 1.1 0
Links 0.9   0
iCab 2.7    0
UC Browser 2.1  0
General Crawlers 0  0
Iron 21.0   0
Midori 1.19 0
Lunascape 4.3   0
UC Browser 6.0  0
Iron 0.4    0
Pale Moon 16.0  0
Opera 5.1   0
Lunascape 4.2   0
Iron 8.06   0
Opera 9.7   0
Epiphany 1.9    0
Camino 0.9  0
Puffin 2.91 0
CE-Preload 0    0
Lunascape 3.1   0
Epiphany 3.4    0
Iceweasel 19.0  0
Iron 23.0   0
iBrowser 0  0
Lunascape 4.1   0
Epiphany 0  0
Sundance 0  0
Pale Moon 93.6  0
Flock 0.8   0
HP Secure Web Browser 1.4   0
Maxthon 3.9 0
Chrome 24.8 0
Links 1.0   0
Netscape 4.71   0
Chrome 0.1  0
VLC 0   0
Epiphany 2.29   0
Chrome 24.7 0
K-Meleon 1.6    0
Camino 2.4  0
Firefox 0.0 0
Firefox 27.0    0
Konqueror 4.6   0
WebTV/MSNTV 2.8 0
Chrome 40.0 0
Silk 1.02   0
Chrome 95.0 0
Baidu Explorer 2.5  0
Amaya 9.5   0
rekonq 1.70 0
Galeon 1.3  0
Comodo Dragon 18.2  0
Baidu Explorer 2.4  0
Maxthon 5.0 0
ogeb browser 1.1    0
Lunascape 1.03  0
Iceweasel 11.0  0
Firefox 3.7 0
Privoxy 0   0
Iceweasel 13.0  0
Firefox 3.2 0
Dillo 0.6   0
Lunascape 3.2   0
OmniWeb 4.5 0
SeaMonkey 2.21  0
iCab 4.0    0
Firefox 3.3 0
Firefox 3.4 0
Opera 10.10 0
Firefox 3.8 0
Chromium 29.0   0
Baidu Explorer 2.3  0
Firefox 3.9 0
Iron 20.0   0
Shiira 1.1  0
RockMelt 0.0    0
iPod Touch 0    0
Epiphany 3.6    0
IBrowse 2.2 0
Microsoft Excel 12.0    0
Microsoft Visio 0   0
w3m 0.4 0
OmniWeb 2.7 0
Shiira 0.9  0
Vienna 3.0  0
Iceweasel 22.0  0
Flock 4.0   0
Sleipnir 2.4    0
Chromium 30.0   0
Firefox 50.0    0
Microsoft 0 0
rekonq 1.81 0
Dillo 0.7   0
Konqueror 4.10  0
iCab 2.8    0
Enigma Browser 0    0
Vienna 2.6  0
Pale Moon 20.2  0
Konqueror 4.8   0
Maxthon 2.5 0
Flock 0 0
Windows Media Player 8.0    0
Camino 1.2  0
w3m 0.2 0
w3m 0.1 0
Maxthon 3.2 0
Midori 0.0  0
Chrome 3.2  0
Anonymizied 0   0
Konqueror 4.4   0
Iceweasel 14.0  0
Epiphany 1.7    0
w3m 0   0
RockMelt 0.44   0
Iceweasel 6.0   0
Firefox 29.0    0
1st ZipCommander 0  0
Sleipnir 2.7    0
Chrome 2.2  0
Firefox 83.0    0
Firefox 26.0    0
RockMelt 0.1    0
Iceweasel 16.0  0
Iceweasel 23.0  0
Kindle 3.8  0
Opera 9.3   0
Iceweasel 7.0   0
Sleipnir 4.2    0
Mozilla 0.9 0
iCab 0  0
Iceweasel 3.6   0
Chrome 19.9 0
Sleipnir 3.9    0
Lunascape 1.04  0
Chrome 38.0 0
Links 0 0
CoRom+ 26.0 0
Opera 9.4   0
Camino 0    0
BITS 0  0
SeaMonkey 2.22  0
Maxthon 3.6 0
Firefox 30.0    0
Opera 9.8   0
Sleipnir 4.3    0
UC Browser 1.9  0
Baidu Explorer 2.2  0
Sleipnir 3.8    0
IE 6.1  0
K-Meleon 1.7    0
Iceweasel 5.0   0
Maxthon 55.5    0
Lunascape 3.4   0
Opera 9.9   0
Zune 3.0    0
RockMelt 2.3    0
Firefox 33.0    0
UC Browser 7.3  0
Windows Media Player 4.0    0
Maxthon 22.0    0
QQ Browser 7.4  0
Opera 8.6   0
Pale Moon 19.1  0
Lunascape 0.98  0
Firefox 90.0    0
Konqueror 4.0   0
Firefox 37.0    0
Chrome 24.9 0
Firefox 62.0    0
Windows Media Player 7.0    0
CoRom+ 0    0
OmniWeb 0   0
Chrome 77.8 0
Iron 22.0   0
Maxthon 4.5 0
WinAmp 0    0
iBrowser 2.6    0
Kindle 4.0  0
Silk 3.3    0
Iceweasel 15.0  0
Maxthon 9.0 0
Maxthon 6.0 0
Sleipnir 4.0    0
Iceweasel 12.0  0
Chrome 18.1 0
Bolt 0  0
Firefox 35.0    0
Chrome 4.9  0
Chrome 2.5  0
Firefox 0.9 0
Chrome 9.2  0
Firefox 28.0    0
Chrome 20.5 0
Epiphany 3.3    0
HP Secure Web Browser 1.7   0
Lunascape 4.5   0
Chrome 02.0 0
Comodo Dragon 25.0  0
SeaMonkey 10.0  0
Konqueror 4.9   0
vobsub 0    0
Chrome 65.0 0
RMA 0   0
Firefox 0.10    0
Midori 1.25 0
MS IPPPD 0  0
Anonymizer 0    0
Minefield 4.2   0
RockMelt 3.1    0
Chrome 22.9 0
Maxthon 10.0    0
Chrome 9.9  0
Comodo Dragon 22.2  0
Chrome 13.6 0
Chrome 23.9 0
Iron 24.0   0
Chrome 92.0 0
Chrome 91.0 0
Sundance 1.0    0
Firefox 0.8 0
Chrome 1.6  0
Chrome 20.2 0
Arora 0.4   0
SeaMonkey 7.0   0
Chrome 29.1 0
MS IPP DAV 0    0
Iceweasel 9.0   0
HP Secure Web Browser 1.8   0
UC Browser 7.1  0
Chrome 16.1 0
Iceweasel 8.0   0
Lynx 2.6    0
Konqueror 4.5   0
MFHttpScan 0    0
Chrome 16.9 0
Maxthon 8.0 0
Chrome 19.1 0
Chrome 17.7 0
Chrome 14.9 0
K-Meleon 1.1    0
SlimBrowser 0   0
Chrome 22.3 0
Pale Moon 17.0  0
Dolfin 2.1  0
Chrome 18.8 0
Chrome 37.0 0
Sleipnir 2.3    0
Chrome 18.5 0
Epiphany 4.3    0
SeaMonkey 8.2   0
Chrome 21.1 0
Chrome 15.3 0
Kindle 3.6  0
Opera 70.0  0
Chrome 1.2  0
Chrome 20.8 0
Chrome 2.7  0
Opera 12.00 0
Chrome 23.6 0
Firefox 7.1 0
Chrome 31.3 0
Opera 12.6  0
Lunascape 0.99  0
IBrowse 1.22    0
Opera 12.2  0
Chrome 21.2 0
Chrome 18.4 0
Chrome 8.8  0
Chrome 1.5  0
Chrome 22.6 0
Epiphany 2.1    0
QuickTime 7.1   0
RealPlayer 0    0
Webaroo 0   0
Chrome 19.8 0
Chrome 38.2 0
Chrome 16.7 0
Chrome 21.5 0
SeaMonkey 13.6  0
Chrome 16.2 0
Chrome 11.8 0
Maxthon 3.14    0
Chrome 14.4 0
Chrome 17.4 0
Comodo Dragon 26.0  0
SeaMonkey 8.6   0
Amaya 9.1   0
Chrome 20.3 0
Chrome 21.9 0
Chrome 22.7 0
Maxthon 3.33    0
K-Meleon 0  0
Dillo 0 0
UC Browser 6.3  0
Chrome 21.7 0
Maxthon 4.90    0
Chrome 6.2  0
Chrome 15.7 0
MS IPP 0    0
Yandex Browser 2.5  0
Maxthon 7.0 0
Firefox 79.0    0
Chrome 20.6 0
Maxthon 4.3 0
Pale Moon 10.0  0
MS Proxy 0  0
Chrome 22.4 0
Iceweasel 4.0   0
Chrome 24.4 0
Ace Explorer 0  0
Firefox 70.0    0
Chrome 14.1 0
Chrome 19.5 0
Firefox 20.1    0
Chrome 23.7 0
Chrome 31.0 0
Chrome 23.8 0
Chrome 15.5 0
Chrome 16.3 0
Chrome 16.4 0
Yandex Browser 0.0  0
Shiira 1.0  0
Chrome 1.4  0
Zune 2.5    0
Iron 30.0   0
Chrome 12.6 0
Chrome 15.8 0
Firefox 61.0    0
Chrome 13.1 0
Chrome 14.6 0
Chrome 22.5 0
iBrowser 2.5    0
Opera 13.0  0
Chrome 17.8 0
Chrome 18.7 0
Chrome 21.4 0
Chrome 6.9  0
Chrome 24.5 0
Chrome 24.6 0
Firefox 80.0    0
Camino 0.0  0
Charlotte 1.1   0
Chrome 7.3  0
Sleipnir 2.5    0
Chrome 20.9 0
Chrome 16.5 0
Sundance 0.99   0
CoRom+ 25.0 0
Chrome 17.6 0
Chrome 18.9 0
Mosaic 3.8  0
Chrome 7.2  0
Chrome 16.8 0
Chrome 15.9 0
Chrome 19.2 0
WebTV/MSNTV 1.2 0
Chrome 20.7 0
Chrome 14.3 0
Kindle 2.0  0
Chrome 17.2 0
w3m 0.3 0
Openwave Mobile Browser 6.2 0
Iron 29.0   0
Sleipnir 3.0    0
Chrome 8.4  0
Chrome 13.8 0
iBrowser 2.4    0
Konqueror 4.3   0
Chrome 15.6 0
Chrome 18.3 0
Chrome 19.4 0
Chrome 20.1 0
Vienna 2.5  0
Chrome 0.9  0
Chrome 19.3 0
SeaMonkey 4.2   0
Comodo Dragon 0 0
Konqueror 4.7   0
Chrome 20.4 0
Chrome 14.7 0
Kindle 3.3  0
Chrome 7.8  0
Chrome 26.7 0
SeaMonkey 9.27  0
Chrome 14.2 0
Chrome 8.3  0
Firefox 40.0    0
Camino 1.8  0
Chrome 22.8 0
Safari 3.3  0
Chrome 15.4 0
Sleipnir 2.2    0
Chrome 9.1  0
Chrome 6.1  0
Chrome 16.6 0
SeaMonkey 3.0   0
Lunascape 1.02  0
Chrome 14.8 0
Chrome 15.1 0
Kindle 3.5  0
Maxthon 25.0    0
Chrome 21.3 0
Chrome 18.2 0
Dillo 3.0   0
iBrowser 2.2    0
Chrome 21.6 0
Chrome 4.5  0
Chrome 2.8  0
Chrome 23.5 0
Dolfin 2.2  0
Chrome 7.1  0
GreenBrowser 0  0
Chrome 10.6 0
Chrome 33.0 0
Chrome 15.2 0
Sleipnir 3.7    0
Chrome 19.6 0
Epiphany 3.22   0
Chrome 3.3  0
MPlayer 1.0 0
Chrome 17.5 0
Chrome 26.4 0
Flock 2.02  0
Chrome 1.7  0
Flock 2.05  0
Chrome 5.1  0
Chrome 2.6  0
Lunascape 0.96  0
SeaMonkey 11.1  0
Kindle 3.2  0
Chrome 9.4  0
UC Browser 5.1  0
Chrome 5.4  0
Chrome 21.8 0
Chrome 17.9 0
Epiphany 2.91   0
Opera 18.2  0
Chrome 5.3  0
Flock 2.07  0
Google Desktop 0    0
Kindle 3.7  0
Firefox 39.0    0
Chrome 22.2 0
Chrome 31.7 0
Chrome 14.5 0
Sundance 2.0    0
Chrome 7.4  0
Iceweasel 0 0
Midori 0.45 0
Chrome 2.9  0
Chrome 34.2 0
Flock 2.09  0
Dillo 2.2   0
Safari 4.9  0
Chrome 17.3 0
Chrome 31.5 0
Charlotte 1.0   0
Maxthon 4.05    0
WordPress 0 0
Opera 12.7  0
Chrome 4.8  0
Yandex Browser 0    0
Safari 11.9 0
Chrome 0.6  0
Netscape 9.2    0
Chrome 33.1 0
Chrome 3.7  0
Chrome 88.8 0
Chrome 7.7  0
Opera 25.0  0
Firefox 45.0    0
Chrome 10.8 0
Chrome 11.5 0
Chrome 0.8  0
Chrome 12.7 0
Flock 2.04  0
Chrome 4.2  0
Safari 26.6 0
Chrome 44.8 0
Sleipnir 0  0
Maxthon 4.2 0
Flock 2.01  0
Vienna 1.2  0
QQ Browser 1.6  0
Chrome 4.4  0
Chrome 28.4 0
Sleipnir 2.30   0
Dillo 2.1   0
Chrome 25.9 0
Lynx 2.7    0
Google 0    0
Kindle 3.1  0
Chrome 6.3  0
Safari 8.6  0
Chrome 12.8 0
K-Meleon 0.8    0
Chrome 61.2 0
Lynx 2.4    0
Flock 7.0   0
Sleipnir 3.6    0
Chrome 10.3 0
Chrome 8.2  0
Chrome 6.8  0
Sleipnir 1.9    0
Chrome 30.3 0
Sleipnir 2.6    0
Mozilla 2.0 0
Chrome 3.5  0
Camino 2.3  0
Chrome 1.8  0
Flock 2.03  0
Sleipnir 2.40   0
Safari 6.2  0
QQ Browser 6.15 0
Opera iPad  0
Mosaic 0    0
Midori 7.9  0
Chrome 5.2  0
Chrome 10.1 0
Kindle 3.4  0
Firefox 16.5    0
Firefox 69.0    0
Sundance 1.1    0
Opera 16.0  0
Mozilla 2.2 0
Chrome 12.2 0
Chrome 8.5  0
CoRom+ 24.0 0
Silk 0  0
Pocket PC 0 0
Escape 0    0
Safari 16.9 0
IE 3.0  0
Safari 9.0  0
Opera 14.2  0
Chrome 47.1 0
Vienna 1.0  0
Chrome 32.7 0
Chrome 9.6  0
Chrome 28.1 0
Chrome 6.4  0
Google Webmaster Tools 0    0
Chrome 8.6  0
Flock 2.06  0
Chrome 9.5  0
Firefox 23.6    0
Chrome 66.0 0
SeaMonkey 1.6   0
Websense 0  0
Chrome 12.5 0
Mozilla 6.0 0
Kindle 4.4  0
Chrome 87.0 0
Firefox 14.6    0
Wipeout Pure 0  0
Chrome 29.9 0
Vienna 0    0
Chromium 18.6   0
Custo 0 0
Chrome 6.6  0
Chrome 11.2 0
Chrome 12.1 0
Firefox 1.1 0
Netscape 9.1    0
Safari 5.9  0
Chrome 8.7  0
Chrome 9.7  0
Chrome 27.8 0
Firefox 4.2 0
Chrome 13.7 0
OmniWeb 5.12    0
Chrome 5.9  0
Chrome 43.4 0
Firefox 82.0    0
Iron 35.5   0
Safari 4.6  0
Chrome 27.6 0
Maxthon 5.2 0
K-Meleon 1.02   0
Chrome 1.9  0
Chrome 43.2 0
Links 2.0   0
Maxthon 4.6 0
Chrome 6.7  0
Chrome 2.3  0
Charlotte 2.1   0
Chrome 25.8 0
K-Meleon 0.9    0
Flock 3.7   0
Dolphin 0.8 0
SeaMonkey 5.9   0
Sleipnir 2.41   0
Beamrise 0.0    0
Firefox 53.0    0
Safari 9.9  0
RockMelt 0.2    0
Safari 11.0 0
Galeon 1.2  0
Chrome 4.3  0
Chrome 12.3 0
Opera 11.7  0
Firefox 13.6    0
Firefox 4.6 0
Phantom 22.0    0
Kindle 1.1  0
rekonq 4.8  0
Epiphany 1.5    0
Maxthon 1.6 0
Dolphin 4.0 0
Chrome 10.4 0
Opera 3.0   0
Chrome 11.1 0
Firefox 74.0    0
Epiphany 3.1    0
Chrome 12.4 0
Firefox 13.2    0
Firefox 9.10    0
Chrome 13.4 0
Yahoo! My Browser 0 0
Chrome 12.9 0
Chrome 27.4 0
MFC Foundation Class Library 0  0
Chrome 6.5  0
Openwave Mobile Browser 6.3 0
Safari 5.4  0
Midori 5.0  0
fantomas fantomCrew Browser 0   0
Maxthon 24.0    0
SeaMonkey 3.15  0
Firefox 15.6    0
OmniWeb 3.0 0
Firefox 56.0    0
Lunascape 0.95  0
Chrome 47.0 0
Firefox 1.6 0
Chrome 25.7 0
QQ Browser 6.40 0
Chrome 37.3 0
Dolphin 3.5 0
Chrome 66.6 0
Chrome 11.9 0
Chrome 34.0 0
Firefox 17.6    0
EVE-minibrowser 0   0
fantomas multiBlocker browser 0 0
Kindle 1.0  0
Chrome 3.6  0
Chrome 5.5  0
Maxthon 4.03    0
SeaMonkey 6.1   0
Chrome 4.6  0
Maxthon 9.9 0
Silk 3.2    0
Chrome 3.9  0
Firefox 30.6    0
Firefox 4.5 0
Dolphin 6.2 0
Firefox 17.1    0
Maxthon 3.1 0
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems local storage is the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle I think so.  I don't think it's unreasonable to ask that small percentage of your users upgrade their browser or use a different browser if they want a modern secure banking solution.

Comment: I Agree, I will discuss this here.